# Use sed to replace a string that contains characters with specials meanings to sed

Tags: command-line, sed

I want to search for the string

```
1 /value Error Code:12345/I
```

And replace it with

```
1 /deleted by user/i
```

How can I do this with `sed`?

Comment: Do the " 1 /.../i" belong to the string? Normally the syntax is simply `sed 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/' FILE, but if the strings contain slashes, you can also use e.g. `s#PATTERN#REPLACEMENT` with `#` as separator.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can use variable separators:

```
$ echo "1 /value Error Code:12345/I " | sed 's;/value.*/I;/deleted by user/i;'
1 /deleted by user/i
```

But if you have to use `/` for whatever reason, you can always prepend `\` to them when they are literal:

```
$ echo "1 /value Error Code:12345/I " | sed 's/\/value.*\/I/\/deleted by user\/i/;'
1 /deleted by user/i
```

Or you could abandon `sed` altogether and use `awk`, with `/` as separator for both input fields and output fields:

```
$ echo "1 /value Error Code:12345/I " | awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$2="deleted by user";$3="i";print}'
1 /deleted by user/i
```

Comment: In the third example, the main block should be `$2="deleted by user";$3="i";print`. @Bala I'm wondering why this answer has not been accepted.